# webmethod is not calling when URL Rewrite using httpmodule

Tags: c#

I've tried to implement url rewriting in my project. Its working fine but all the WebMethods are not working after the url rewrite. I'v did it with the HttpModule. Following are my codes. Could you please help me.

Client Side

```
function MyMethod() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Test.aspx/TestMethos',
                async: true,
                cache: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                data: '{}',
                success: function (data) {
                       //MyCode
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    if (request.statusText == 'Unauthorized') {
                        //Logout
                    }

}
```

WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
public static string TestMethod()
{
    return "Hi Test";
}
```

HttpModule ReWrite C# Code

```
HttpApplication MyApp = (HttpApplication)sender;
           string MyOldPath = MyApp.Request.Path;
           string OriginalURL = string.Empty;
           switch (MyOldPath.ToLower())
           {
               case "/home":
                   string selectedQueryString = MyApp.Request.QueryString.ToString();
                   OriginalURL = "~/Modules/UserMgmt/Home.aspx";
                   break;
               case "/star performer":
                   OriginalURL = "~/Modules/UserMgmt/BestEmployee.aspx";
                   break;
                case "/test.aspx/testmethos;:
                   OriginalURL = "~/Modules/UserMgmt" + MyOldPath;
                   break;


}

if (OriginalURL != string.Empty)
    MyApp.Context.RewritePath(OriginalURL, string.Empty, string.Empty);
```

Comment: you have a typo in your ajax call `'Test.aspx/TestMethos'` it must be `method`. Also in your rewrite you have the same mistake because your webmethod is called `TestMethod` not `TestMethos`

Comment: Inclusive of the spelling mistakes, this line is wrong in your rewrite:
`case "/test.aspx/testmethos;:` It should be 
`case "/test.aspx/testmethod":`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually that spelling mistake is happend when I copied the code it into the stack overflow. Its correct in my project and its working If not using any url rewiting.